# soap throws function name error in php

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am calling the below wsdl url from soap using PHP

```
 $response = new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.8:8080/myAPI/ws/TESTWS?wsdl");
```

I am checking the function name from soapclient return values using

```
 $soapFunctions = $response->__getFunctions();
 print_r($soapFunctions);
```

It returns

```
Array
(
 [0] => sampleMethodResponse sampleMethod(sampleMethod $parameters)
)
```

Then i am sending value to the wsdl function using the __soapcall function using the above return function name "sampleMethod".

```
try{
$soapstr = $response->__soapCall("sampleMethod", array( 'userId'       => "8561",
            'value'       => "test",
            'type'       => "1",
            'send'       => "1",
    ));
     echo "Response:\n" . $soapstr->__getLastResponse(). "\n";
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

The above code returns the below error

```
#0 /home/karthik/git/PHPFrontend/easymedmobile.com/htdocs/wsdl/index.php(56): SoapClient->__soapCall('sampleMethod', Array)
#1 {main}
```

Help in this issue, what i am doing wrong in this file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise to also `echo $e->getMessage();` instead of only the backtrace? Knowing _what_ went wrong is most of the battle ;)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual exception and not just the trace. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: It returns "Precondition" if i use $e->getMessage();

Comment: Find the below error in detials
 

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Precondition in /home/desktop/test/htdocs/wsdl/index.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 /home/karthik/git/PHPFrontend/easymedmobile.com/htdocs/wsdl/index.php(56): SoapClient->__soapCall('sampleMethod', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/karthik/git/PHPFrontend/easymedmobile.com/htdocs/wsdl/index.php on line 56

Comment: That's all? Not even 'Precondition failed?'? Well, set `'trace' => true` in the options and let's see the last response & response headers shed some light..

Comment: Seeing the response in the deleted answer: your server is misbehaving on `/home/desktop/test/htdocs/wsdl/index.php:56` it seems, not your client...

Comment: IF i send like below format its working fine. what wrong in the above format, which i send early.

   $soapstr = $response->__soapCall("sampleMethod",array("parameters" => array( 'userId'       => "8561",
  'value'       => "sample data for notification ws",
  'type'       => "1",
  'send'       => "0",
)));